# A basic logic puzzle with character!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

120 + 170 + 78 = x

**Question**

Is the above equation correct? Please answer Yes or No with reasons (at least three good and very specific reasons which can be seen clearly once you understand).*

---

**Notes**

1. Well actually they can be seen clearly even if you don't understand! Hints will follow at some point if necessary.
2. The three reasons all apply to the *same* answer. There aren't three reasons and three different answers.
3. The necessary clues are there. If you don't get the 3 clues you won't get the complete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> Yes, because according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X#Computing_codes), 
>  the UTF-8 decimal value for the Latin Small Letter x is 120. 
>  While the hex value for the Latin Small Letter x is 78.
>  Additionally, the octal value of the Lowercase x is 170.
> (Thanks to @Stiv for pointing me to the necessary [list](https://www.ascii-code.com/))
>  Using “+” as a logical symbol for “or”, we get 120 or 170 or 78 = x.
>  So, the answer would be yes.
>  However, finding the three clues that links the three to this answer was quite trying.
>  My first thought is the usage of x to mean cross or trans. So, by **trans**posing the three exes atop one another, creates one x. (Which turns out was not the OP’s intention)
>  My second thought is the title using the words as the clues was confirmed by OP.
>  - "character" clues to the use of a character code chart to find x's value.
>  - "basic" clues to the use of BASE-n coding, dec(Base-10) ,hex(Base-16), oct(Base-8)
>  - "logic" as pointed out by OP refers to basic logic symbols where “+” is substituted for the word “or”. So the equation means **a or b or c = x**.

Comment: Try rot13(bpgny) on [this list](https://www.ascii-code.com/)...

Comment: Well done and not a coincidence! You haven't yet identified and explained the 3 clues that say why though - at least not formally. Hint rot13(Nanylfr gur urpx bhg bs gur gvgyr!)

Comment: Yes, rot13("k" vf n punenpgre), you just have to explain rot13("onfvp" and ""ybtvp"). I feel a bit mean but this is where all the clues are! Note: You are already as near as dammit.

Comment: rot13( Zbfg crbcyr guvax bs + zrnavat nqqvgvba. Ubjrire, nf V fnl va gur gvgyr, guvf vf n ybtvp chmmyr (urapr abe nytroen be nevguzrgvp). Unir n ybbx ng gur ybtvp flzobyf urer uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Yvfg_bs_ybtvp_flzobyf )

Comment: Huh. I never knew that. I’m on mobile so that took me a while to translate and look up. I’ll try to fix it later today then clean it up tomorrow if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

One of the answers are:

> YES
>  x is a variable which means it is mutable allowing you to make it any number you want

Comment: Not what I have in mind. Keep trying though.  P.S. rot13(Jub fnlf k vf n inevnoyr? Abg zr!)